# WKWebView Clear Local Storage Between Builds

Tags: swift, local-storage, wkwebview

I'm building an app with an embedded WKWebview. The WKWebView presents a website which sets and reads some local storage.

The configuration is pretty basic:

```swift
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.somewebsite.com")!))
```

When I archive/distribute the app for testing the built product "remembers" everything that has been stored in local storage during development – i.e. when I build & run the app in Xcode, set some local storage in the window. That same data is "remembered" in the archived distributable.

Is there a way to clear it during each build/archival?

Comment: The local storage can't be part of the build. It's local storage kept on the device, not as part of the app. If you want to clear the app's local storage, delete the app from the device before installing the next build or archive.

Comment: That was my assumption. I thought that if I deleted the build/archive and perhaps -rebuilt the app again, the locally stored data would be gone in the newly built app. But it isn't. It's still there, persisting…